# How real time volumetric light beam effect could be achieved in opengl?

Tags: opengl, c++, lighting

Here is 1.5 mins long [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zLNKNHn-XM) to give you an example of what I meant. From research that I did , regarding lighting effect, usually it is done offline (post-processing) using algorithms like "god rays" or "ray marching" with "volumetric fog" but how to achieve the same result in real time? Do I have to draw a cone? If yes, then should it be only the shell of a cone  meaning   that cone is empty inside? Or even inside of a cone there should be vertices?

Question: What techniques or algorithms are used to achieve such a result?

**EDIT 1:**

Just an example what I am working on.
Here I do have 2 objects (a human object and a cube). I am using cube to simulate x-ray machine and currently I am trying to added x-ray beam effect which has to be in the shape of pyramid. However I have troubles building the effect of the beam.

My scene:

[image]

god ray fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
  
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform vec2 lightPositionOnScreen;
uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

const float exposure = 0.3f;
const float decay = 0.96815 ; // 0.96815 
const float density  = 0.926;
const float weight  = 0.1; // 0.587
const int NUM_SAMPLES = 100;

void main()
{ 
    vec2 deltaTexCoord = vec2(TexCoords.xy - lightPositionOnScreen.xy);   
    vec2 texCoord = TexCoords;
 
    deltaTexCoord *= 1.0f / NUM_SAMPLES * density;   

    vec3 color = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords).rgb; 
   
    float illuminationDecay = 1.0f;   
   
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)   
    {         
        texCoord -= deltaTexCoord;     
  
        vec3 sample = texture(screenTexture, texCoord).rgb;     
       
        sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;     
   
        color += sample;     
   
        illuminationDecay *= decay;   
    }
    
    FragColor  = vec4(color * exposure, 1.0);
}
```

god ray vertex shader:

````
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
}  
```
````

Comment: You've tagged your question with Unity (which uses C# scripting and a variant of DirectX-style HLSL for its shaders), OpenGL and C++, which Unity does not use directly. This is a bit confusing for someone who wants to give you an answer you can apply in your game immediately. Which technology are you actually using for your game? Just searching "Unity god-ray" turns up lots of examples of how to do this in realtime in that engine. What have you tried based on your research so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @DMGregory , I am using opengl. I tagged unity as the example that I am referring to is from unity game engine.

Comment: Searching "OpenGL god-ray" also turns up lots of examples and tutorials for how to achieve this effect in realtime. Which ones have you tried using so far, and where do you need help with your current attempt?

Comment: @DMGregory , thanks for your help. I edited my question and added my project description so you could get an idea what I am working on. The problem is that I do not understand how to build the beam. 1) I was suggested to build a cone (or pyramid) and then using fragment shader change the color of a fragment depending on the distance from light source. 2) Then I was suggested to use "god rays" algorithm but due to the fact that scene consists of only 2 objects and there is nothing else in the scene I do not get so called "proper beams". Should I add a fog? What are your suggestions?

Comment: Your scene looks quite good already! What about it would you like to change? What should it look like instead?

Comment: @DMGregory , I wan to achieve "proper visible beam" like in a video that I posted in the question. Because right now it is difficult to see beam as it is "not continuous" on "empty space".